# ms word not showing the underlining (dots) under hidden text

Tags: microsoft-word

My hidden body text doesn't have the dotted underline.

If I right-click > Font then it shows  that text is hidden (checkbox for "hidden" is set).
If I toggle the Home tab > Paragraph "P" (paragraph symbol) still no underline dots.
However, shows hidden underline dots for headings.

I'm in Print Layout mode

View > Outline mode:   no hidden underline dots
View > Print Layout:   no body hidden underline dots .  Shows heading hidden underline dots
View > Draft:

Comment: This may be easier to understand if you included some screencaps